# ¿How to find request's parameters @ debug mode?

Tags: java, debugging, servlets, netbeans, request

Excuse my writing, but English is not my native tongue.

This is my situation: I'm checking source code of a web application base on **Java**.

Well, when I want a parameter of `request` variable, I call `request.getParameter(key)`. But there is **an missing parameter**, and I executed the application in debug mode, thus, I can look for the parameter. But I don't find the parameters anywhere. Can somebody help me?

I use ***NetBeans IDE*** for development.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `getParameterMap` from `Request` object 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()

if it isn't there you need to check whether your parameter is passed from browser - you can check `network` tab in Chrome development tools

Comment: Network tab in Chrome Development tool is the best place to check on the real request and its parameters